# UISplitViewController presenting over current context from detail View

Tags: xcode, swift, ipad

I have a split view controller with master view being something like a menu allowing users to pick the scene for detail view (I have multiple detail views). On one of the detailView scene, I have a button that presents a view controller modally and "Over Current Context" as it has a translucent background and I wanted to create that fog effect. This particular detailView (lets call it TodayViewController) is also the initial detail view controller when the app loads, and only changes when user selects a new view controller from the master view (menu).

This is what I meant in code:

- When app just starts:

  ```
  splitViewController.viewControllers[1] // returns TodayViewController
  ```
- When user selects from the menu:

  ```
  splitViewController.viewControllers[1] // returns a different view controller
  ```

So the issue I am having is that when the app just starts (bullet 1), when I present a child view controller of TodayViewController modally and "over current context", the child VC presents itself over both the master view (menu) as well as the detail view (TodayViewController), causing the entire screen to have a foggy effect. **This is the effect that I want**

However when I select another view controller (from the menu) and then select back TodayViewController and try to present the child VC it only presents itself over the detail view now. Meaning that the foggy effect is only present on the detail view and the master view (the menu again) remains clear. How do I fix this?

I hope I'm clear enough with my explanation. Here are some of my code:

- My GlobalSplitViewController.swift:

  ```
  import UIKit

  class GlobalSplitViewController: UISplitViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

  func primaryViewControllerForCollapsingSplitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController) -> UIViewController? {

      let detailViewController = self.viewControllers[1] as! TodayViewController

      return detailViewController
  }

  func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

      return true

  }

  func splitViewController(svc: UISplitViewController, shouldHideViewController vc: UIViewController, inOrientation orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) -> Bool {
      return false
  }


  }
  ```

GlobalSplitViewController is structured so that TodayViewController is presented first on iPhones, but on iPad it shows both master and detail view, uncollapsed.

Answer (score 0):

'Over current context' is supposed to present over only the master or the detail wherever it is called from. I'm not sure why it doesn't work properly at first (but I understand that's what you want) but then works when you select another option. Anyhow, to achieve what you want, stop using 'over current context'. That will present the fog vc over the whole screen.